# how to join tables with extra condition

Tags: mysql, join

am having trouble figuring how to do a join when there is an additional condition on which rows in the joined table to import.

members

```
id|name
```

contacts

```
id|name
```

membercontact

```
id|memberid|contactid|myid

1|1|33|2
2|1|34|3

SELECT m.*,c.*,cm.* 
FROM `members` m
LEFT JOIN `contacts`c
  ON c.memberid = m.id
LEFT JOIN `membercontact` mc
  ON m.id = mc.memberid AND mc.myid ='3'
WHERE m.id = '2'
GROUP BY m.id
```

does not work.  On the other hand, if I remove the mc.myid = 3 condition, it returns the first case where m.id = mc.memberid ie m.id = 2, which is not what I want.

Can anyone suggest proper way to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `membercontact` decomposes the relationship between members and contacts - but you've got them joined directly in that query?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is using `left join`:

```
SELECT m.*,c.*,cm.* 
FROM `members` m LEFT JOIN
     `contacts`c
      ON c.memberid = m.id LEFT JOIN
     `membercontact` mc
      ON m.id = mc.memberid AND mc.myid ='3'
WHERE m.id = '2'
GROUP BY m.id;
```

It is going to return *all* members, because that is how `left join` works.  If you want to filter things, change the `left join` to `inner join`:

```
SELECT m.*,c.*,cm.* 
FROM `members` m INNER JOIN
     `contacts`c
      ON c.memberid = m.id INNER JOIN
     `membercontact` mc
      ON m.id = mc.memberid AND mc.myid ='3'
WHERE m.id = '2'
GROUP BY m.id;
```